# How do we modify HQL transformer while loading a specific parent or another mapped entity property?

Tags: hibernate, hql, resulttransformer

This is an important addition especially to solve performance issues while being able to write efficient dynamic HQL queries.

But, how do we modify the HQL transformer in case of loading a specific parent or another mapped entity property?

The following code:

```
session.createQuery(
    "select st.stNumber as stNumber, st.stDate as stDate "
    + " from SomeTable st "
    + " where st.someTableId < 1000")
    .setResultTransformer( Transformers.aliasToBean(database.SomeTable.class))
.list();
```

works fine, but what if I want to load some of its parents' properties only?

For example, let's say, `SomeTable` has a parent called `SomedParent` and I want to access one of the fields of this parent only?

```
session.createQuery(
    "select st.stNumber as stNumber, st.stDate as stDate, st.someParent.someParentField as someParentField "
    + " from SomeTable st "
    + " where st.someTableId < 1000")
    .setResultTransformer( Transformers.aliasToBean(database.SomeTable.class))
.list();
```

So any ideas?

Comment: create DTO Object and transform query result to that

Answer (score 0):

You are almost right.

First, you create the `SomeTable`:

```
class SomeTable {
    private Long stNumber;
    private Date stDate;
    private String someParentField;

    //getters and setters
}
```

And your query:

```
session.createQuery(
    "select st.stNumber as stNumber, st.stDate as stDate, someParent.someParentField as someParentField "
    + " from SomeTable st "
    + " JOIN st.someParent someParent"
    + " where st.someTableId < 1000")
    .setResultTransformer( Transformers.aliasToBean(SomeTable.class))
.list();
```

In this case, you don’t need to create a constructor for the `SomeTable` class.